# Why after posting from Curl does the page only display correctly in Incognito mode?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, session-cookies

This is a really interesting problem related to cookies, I believe.

My `index.php` has a form, and it posts to `post.php`.  `post.php` then manipulates the data and uses `curl` to then post it to `webinarjam.net`, a 3rd-party service not controlled by me.

`webinarjam.net` then displays a short success message that basically just contains a unique URL. The unique URL is to a thank-you page (hosted by `webinarjam.net`).

**This all works beautifully. But here is the problem:**

**Clicking the URL only works in Incognito mode** (?!) (i.e. clearing browser cookies first). Otherwise, `webinarjam.net` simply displays "Internal Server Error".

I have no idea why the presence of cookies would PREVENT a page from displaying.

How could I change my `post.php` such that the unique thank-you page URL will display correctly even without using Incognito mode of the browser?

Figuring this out would enable me to simply automatically redirect the user to that thank-you page URL upon form submission.  (Currently, redirecting would just bring her to a page that says "Internal Server Error".)

P.S. In case this helps, I've also used the Advanced Rest Client extension within Chrome to try to post the same query data to `webinarjam.net`; the resulting unique thank-you page URL is then able to be displayed without using Incognito mode. So... what I need help figuring out is: what difference exists between the way my `post.php` and the Advanced Rest Client extension are posting to `webinarjam.net`?

Comment: Can you show us post.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally noticed that it wasn't just Incognito mode that worked; it was any browser OTHER than my main one.

And I eventually figured out that it was because my main browser was logged into the EverWebinar site.

I guess EverWebinar barfs (fails) whenever a logged-in admin of a webinar submits a form to sign up for that webinar (even using a different email address).

It seems like upon form submission, the system notices the session/cookies of the logged-in admin, and it says "no matter what, someone who owns this webinar shouldn't be signing up for it."